# Prove that $ \int_{\mathbb R} g(x)d\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} g(x)f(x)dx. $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be a non-negative Lebesgue measurable function such that $\int_I f(x)dx<\infty$ for all finite intervals $I=[a,b]$. For every Lebesgue-measurable set $A\subset\mathbb R$, define $$ \mu(A)=\int_Af(x)dx. $$
>   Prove that if $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a Lebesgue-measurable function, then $$ \int_{\mathbb R} g(x)d\mu(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} g(x)f(x)dx. $$

---

I know that this is a direct result of [Radon–Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) but can we show the identity above only with the help of basic Lebesgue-integral theory? WLG we can assume $g(x)\ge 0$ and consider the simple functions approximation. However, I find it hard if we only use the definition of the integral of non-negative functions. Can someone give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: What counts as "basic Lebesgue-integral theory"? E.g. is the monotone convergence theorem allowed?

Comment: @carmichael561 Sorry, I didn't make this clear enough. Yes, the monotone convergence thm, dominated convergence thm, Fatou's lemma are counted.

Comment: Have you tried proving this statement for $g$ defined on finite intervals?

Comment: @SeanNemetz I did not... should have realized this earlier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired equality holds when $g$ is an indicator function by definition, hence when $g$ is a simple function by linearity. And if $g\geq 0$, let $\{\phi_n\}$ be a sequence of simple functions increasing to $g$, then by two applications of the monotone convergence theorem we have
$$ \int g(x)\;d\mu(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int \phi_n(x)\;d\mu(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int \phi_n(x)f(x)\;dx=\int g(x)f(x)\;dx$$

Comment: Thank you! I should have considered first when $g$ is an indicator function...